# How to build PDFbox in VBScript

Tags: .net, vbscript, pdfbox

Is it possible to use PDFbox in VBscript , I have tried with .Net & Java to autofill the PDF forms ,it works perfectly but I have no idea about its capability with VBscript.
Can any one share your views 
Thanks